# PHP readline() when STDIN other than keyboard

Tags: php, stream, redirect, stdin, readline

I'm writing an script that is able to read from stdin and then request for confirmation.

```
<?php
$stream = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$input = fgets($stream, 1024);
$confirmation = readline('Are you sure?');
if ( $confirmation == 'y' )
    /* Do dangerous stuff */
```

When I run it directly:

```
$ php script.php
inputdata
^D
Are you sure?
```

But I'm trying to run it using a file as STDIN. In that case, readline() returns false and no confirmation is prompted.

```
$ php script.php < data.txt
```

or

```
$ echo "foobar" | php script.php
```

How can I read both from the STDIN and keyboard when invoking this script in this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [fgetc](http://php.net/fgetc) function with `STDIN`. See example bellow.

```
$input = fgets(STDIN, 1024);
echo "\nAre you sure?\n";
$conf = fgetc(STDIN);
if($conf=='y'){
        echo "Great! Lets go ahead\n";
}else{
        echo "Okay, May be next time\n";
}
```

#### Console output

Sample 1

```
    $ echo 'data
    > y
    > ' | php php_readline.php

    Are you sure? 
    Great! Lets go ahead
```

Sample 2

```
$ php php_readline.php 
Some data

Are you sure?
n
Okay, May be next time
```

Comment: Unfortunately your approach doesn't work for me. fgetc is still consuming the stream.

Comment: Did you used the same code I wrote or changed it?  If changed show me the code. What is os, kernel?

Answer (score 3):

According to a commenter ont he PHP page ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php ):

> When readline is enabled, php switches the terminal mode to accept
>   line-buffered input.  This means that the proper way to use the cli
>   when you pipe to an interactive command is to explicitly specify that
>   php is not using the terminal for input:
>
> php somescript.php < /dev/null | less

I believe the point is to append `| less`. Not knowing the structure of your data, presumably something might need to be done within your script to handle the transition from data to confirmation.

One might add a mechanism to detect when terminal line-buffered input is enabled.